# In SwiftUI, how to implement something like `navigationBarItems(...)`

Tags: swiftui

I've had some problems with SwiftUI's navigation API, so I'm experimenting with implementing my own. Parts of this are relatively easy: I create a class `NavModel` that is basically a stack. Depending on what's on the top of that stack, I can display different views.

But I can't see how to implement something like SwiftUI's `.navigationBarItems(...)`. That view modifier seems to use something like the Preferences API to pass its argument `View` *up* the hierarchy to the containing navigation system. Eg:

```swift
VStack {
    ... 
}.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Edit") { startEdit() })
```

Anything that goes through `onPreferenceChange(...)` has to be `Equatable`, so if I want to pass an `AnyView?` for the navigation bar items, I need to somehow may it `Equatable`, and I don't see how to do that.

Here's some sample code that shows a basic push and pop navigation. I'm wondering: how could I make the `navBarItems(...)` work? (The UI is ugly, but that's not important now.)

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var navModel: NavModel = .shared
    var body: some View {
        NavView(model: navModel) { node in
            switch node {
            case .root:  rootView
            case .foo: fooView
            }
        }
    }
    var rootView: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is the root")
            Button {
                navModel.push(.foo)
            } label: {
                Text("Push a view")
            }
        }
    }
    var fooView: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Foo")
            Button {
                navModel.pop()
            } label: {
                Text("Pop nav stack")
            }
        }.navBarItems(trailing: Text("Test"))
    }
}

struct NavView<Content: View>: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: NavModel
    let makeViews: (NavNode) -> Content
    init(model: NavModel, @ViewBuilder makeViews: @escaping (NavNode) -> Content) {
        self.model = model
        self.makeViews = makeViews
    }
    @State var navItems: AnyView? = nil
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let node = model.stack.last!
            navBar
            Divider()
            makeViews(node)
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                // This doesn't compile
                .onPreferenceChange(NavBarItemsPrefKey.self) { v in
                    navItems = v
                }
        }
    }

    var navBar: some View {
        HStack {
            if model.stack.count > 1 {
                Button {
                    model.pop()
                } label: { Text("Back") }
            }
            Spacer()
            if let navItems = self.navItems {
                navItems
            }
        }
    }
}


enum NavNode {
    case root
    case foo
}

class NavModel: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = NavModel()
    @Published var stack: [NavNode]
    init() {
        stack = [.root]
    }
    func push(_ node: NavNode) { stack.append(node) }
    func pop() {
        if stack.count > 1 {
            stack.removeLast()
        }
    }

}

struct NavBarItemsPrefKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = AnyView?
    static var defaultValue: Value = nil
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        let n = nextValue()
        if n != nil {  // ???
            value = n
        }
    }

}

// Is this the right way? But then anything passed to navBarItems(...) would need 
// to be Equatable. The common case - Buttons - are not.
struct AnyEquatableView: Equatable {
    ???
    init<T>(_ ev: EquatableView<T>) {
        ???
    }

    static func == (lhs: AnyEquatableView, rhs: AnyEquatableView) -> Bool {
        ???
    }
}

struct NavBarItemsModifier<T>: ViewModifier where T: View {
    let trailing: T
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.preference(key: NavBarItemsPrefKey.self, value: AnyView(trailing))
    }
}

extension View {
    func navBarItems<T>(trailing: T) -> some View where T: View {
        return self.modifier(NavBarItemsModifier(trailing: trailing))
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't specific to your question but I implemented a basic one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69982225/im-trying-to-implement-a-view-stack-in-swiftui-and-my-state-objects-are-being/69996884#69996884). I don't thing `navigationBarItems` which is deprecated uses `PreferenceKey` at all I think it just writes to the underlying `UINavigationController` but that is just a guess.

Comment: It can be direct injection, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61487233/12299030, but actually we can only guess and, moreover, as it is internal implementation it can be different in different versions of SwiftUI.